# iOS + jqueryMobile unable to capture webview event when html file is loaded

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, jquery-mobile

I am loading a jqueryMobile html file into webview and webViewDidFinishLoad event is properly triggered. However, when you select a navigation button of loaded jqMb file that loads another html file content, event is not fired! how to capture it? Thank you

Comment: You can use JavaScript events that jQuery Mobile exposes: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html. See `pageinit`, it's the `document.ready` for jQuery Mobile.

Comment: I can capture event properly on jqueryMobile when button is pressed! but how to fire then native webview event? shouldStartLoadWithRequest

Comment: solved using fake javascript call, widow.location = "localFuction". Then - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest is triggered ad if if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"localFunction"]) { Return NO; Hope this helps

Comment: You should post that as an answer so people who stumble across this page know you fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved using fake javascript call, `widow.location = "localFuction"`.

Then, `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest` is triggered and if `([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"localFunction"]) { Return NO`;

Hope this helps

Comment: I know this is an old post, but where/how are you calling the `window.location = "localFunction"` ?