# jQuery Mobile is NOT triggering webViewDidStartLoad and webViewDidFinishLoad after leaving homepage in webView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, jquery-mobile, uiwebview

I have a simple iOS app with a single view that contains a UIWebView. Within my webView, I display my jQuery Mobile website.

Since jQuery Mobile loads pages via ajax, the `webViewDidStartLoad` and `webViewDidFinishLoad` methods are NOT called once the initial page loads. I've found similar questions on SO such as **[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436899/ios-jquerymobile-unable-to-capture-webview-event-when-html-file-is-loaded)**, but I'm not sure where to use the `window.location = "localFunction"` call, and no one has yet to confirm this actually works.

Here's my issue (example):

1. App Starts
2. `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` is called
3. `webViewDidStartLoad` is called, and network activity indicator is shown.
4. `webViewDidFinishLoad` is called, network activity indicator is hidden, and webView displays the initial web page.
5. User clicks a link from the homepage
6. `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` is called
7. The second page is displayed, but `webViewDidStartLoad` and
   `webViewDidFinishLoad` are not called again for the duration of the
   session.

Is there a way to force jQuery Mobile or the iOS app to call `webViewDidStartLoad` and `webViewDidFinishLoad` so that I can do a simple task, such as show a network activity indicator when `webViewDidStartLoad` is called, and hide it when `webViewDidFinishLoad` is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to signal the `UIWebView` of page changes; you can use the custom-scheme launching option as discussed in the SO post in your question.

Define a `window.location` change in the `pagebeforechange` handler: ([JQM Page change events](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html))

```
logToIosConsole: function(msg){ 
    console.log("logToIosConsole: log://"+msg); 
    var standalone = window.navigator.standalone, 
    userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(), 
    safari = /safari/.test( userAgent ), 
    ios = /iphone|ipod|ipad/.test( userAgent ); 

    if( ios ) { 
        if ( !standalone && !safari ) { 
            //uiwebview 
            window.location = "log://"+msg; 
        }; 
    } else { 
        //not iOS 
    };
```

Use it in javascript

```
$(document).on("pagebeforechange", function(eve, ui){
    logToIosConsole("pagebeforechange called on "+eve.currentTarget.URL);
});
```

Intercept this custom-url-scheme in your `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSString *theAnchor=[[[request URL] absoluteString] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
    if([theAnchor hasPrefix:@"log:\/\/"]) {
        NSString *logText=[theAnchor substringFromIndex:@"log:\/\/".length];
        NSLog(@"LogMsg==>%@",logText);
        return NO; 
    }
}
```

Comment: With ajax enabled, the `webViewDidStartLoad` function is still not being called, even with the "mylog" thing.

Comment: updated with code from my current project where I log to Xcode console from JS...

Comment: Can you give me a quick explanation as to what this will do? (thanks ahead of time)

Comment: When running inside a UIWebView, all calls to logToIosConsole(msg) from Javascript will log the "msg" to the xCode/iOS console. The log:// acts as a bridge for sending msg from JS to ObjC.

Comment: I don't think that this will still call the `webViewDidStartLoad` and `webViewDidFinishLoad`. Look at my answer above yours - it seems to be a problem with jQuery Mobile loading pages via Ajax. I really appreciate the help though!

Comment: You are right. This will not invoke `webViewDid*Load` methods. But what you can do is place a `logToIosConsole` call before and after the actual `changePage` and execute the required ObjC code when intercepting `log://` in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`.

Comment: I probably won't use this at the moment, but that's good to know! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`webViewDidStartLoad` and `webViewDidFinishLoad` are only invoked when `window.location` changes. `UIWebView` cannot intercept Ajax calls.

You can either turn-off JQM's Ajax navigation - globally by setting `ajaxEnabled="false"` or individual pages/links using `data-ajax="false"`.

OR

If the problem is simply showing an activity indicator; you could use JQM's in-built activity indicator by invoking `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response... My JQM activity indicator is showing, I'm just wanting to call some other things within my app that would be called by the `webViewDidStartLoad` and `webViewDidFinishLoad` methods. So turning off the ajax navigation is the only work-around? I'll try it real quick...

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with the way the jQuery Mobile site renders pages. They DO get called if you disable ajax navigation for the site. With Ajax ENABLED, the webViewDidStartLoad never gets called when clicking a link because since the page is requested through Ajax, the window location doesn't change, and therefore iOS doesn't register a page change or page load.